# Creating a new column from existing column of z-scores, w/ some replaced with 0 or N/A

Tags: r, psych

I'm new to programming and data analyses using R (I'm a 2nd yr graduate student in psychology, trying to become well-versed in R).

Anyhow, here's my very basic issue:

I have my data in long-format. I'm looking at different RT scores in my data.frame I've imported to R. Currently, I've converted one column of my raw data into z-scores that corresponds/lines up with my raw data scores.

Now, I'd like to make a new column of my raw data scores with z-scores of +/- 1.96 removed.

Alternatively, I would like to know how to create a new column based on my raw scores that automatically replaces values that are +/- 2SD's away from the mean with values that are 0 or "NA".

Thanks all! Great community you guys have here and I plan on learning a lot. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  It helps if you can provide some example code and data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subset operator `[`.  Suppose you have a vector, `myData`.  You can add it like so:

```
cutoff <- 1.96
myData[abs(myData) > cutoff] <- NA
```

It is better not to use `0` because `0` is a possible value.  Use `NA` instead.  Also, it is helpful to add an extra variable: `cutoff` to make modifying and reading the code easier.

To create a new vector, you can use `ifelse`

```
newVector <- ifelse(abs(myData) > cutoff, NA, myData)
```

You can put them together as:

```
newData <- cbind(myData, newVector)
```

or, if `myData` was a dataframe,

```
myData$newVector <- ifelse(abs(myData) > cutoff, NA, myData)
```

will add a new column to the data frame.

Comment: Hey Christopher! Thanks so much for you prompt response. I actually realized I didn't ask my full question (only partial). I'm going to try and take some of you example and implement it in what I need, but perhaps others could shed light on the last part?

Thanks!

Comment: I updated to better answer what I think you are asking.

Comment: Thank you so much Christopher. Sorry for not being very clear. I will update shortly.

Comment: I think it is clear, I just read it again fast because I was called away and wanted to clear it up quickly.

Comment: Hey Christopher, just wanted to thank you again for your help and thoughtful comments throughout that help explain the mechanics of your code. Very appreciative, thank you good sir.

Comment: Hey Christopher, so I have another quick question for you (feel free to ignore as you've helped enough). Anyway, it seems when I'm trying to run this code on my personal machines I get the following "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 'x'kb". I realize this is an issue with my memory/processor. Any work around code or packages that can deal with this? (I should add that my data.frame has almost 16,000 rows of data). Thanks!